# How can I convert monsters from D&D 3.5 to d20 Modern?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, d20-modern

What sort of issues would I run into if I wanted to co-opt some D&D 3.5 creatures into a D20 Modern setting? I'm looking mostly at devils, demons and some of the astral creatures.

Will such creatures likely need re-balancing, or should I be able to get away with throwing them in with few if any changes?

Alternatively, is there any existing material that describes these sorts of creatures that is made specifically for d20 Modern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The systems are very similar.  For your particular question you need to consider a few things.

- Magic likely isn't as common, so that `Magic` and `Cold Iron` damage resistance is often to be the equivalent `DR 5/-`.  Even if you're running a game with a player caster they will never be as powerful as a D&D Wizard (start by subtracting 3 levels).
- Massive Damage is a more important rule, and much closer to home.  It's not a flat 50 for all medium creatures, it's now *usually* the character's constitution modifier.  So if that fast hero with a 12 `Con` takes 15 points of damage she has to make a `Fort` save or go straight to `-1`.  A demon that can do 45 points of damage at a hit is now much more lethal.
- Healing is harder.  Characters are usually limited to `first aid` with replaces 1-10 HP, natural rest, or surgery (which requires downtime).  If you include healing casters, remember they will *not* be the equivalent of a cleric (Start by subtracting 3 levels).

So in general, a little re-balancing is needed, but not a complete re-write.

There are two books which contain a fair number of possible creatures for you.

- [Urban Arcana](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786926597)
- [Menace Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786928999)

Comment: Urban Arcana is already part of the game, but I've limited my players to the core book for the first few levels (most of them are D&D first-timers). I've been browsing over the Menace Manual too, but there doesn't seem to be too many things in the angel/devils/demons vein, especially for angels.

Comment: Yes, angels will likely have to be converted.  I would start by modifying DR and dropping a few Spell Likes.  Obviously stick to the lower levels.  I don't like fighting [Solars](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/angel.htm#angelSolar) at 20th level in D&D!

Comment: So, general starting place would be tuning up their CR by 2-3, tuning down their damage to mostly fit inside the new Massive Damage levels. Do you think the DR needs playing with with a buffed CR?

Comment: @Matthew It depends on how much magic you make available.  If players are walking around with +3 M60s with cold iron bullets ...